# Microsoft Project 2010 - Remove resource leveling but keep schedule

Tags: microsoft-project, microsoft-project-2010, microsoft-project-2013

We are developing a complex task list with resource leveling in Project 2010.

This task list needs to be incorporated into a larger Project which is not using resource leveling and *does not want the resources included*.  Is there a way to lock the schedule that has been generated using resource leveling, but remove the resources from the project?

We know that this will mean that the copy without the resources will not be able to be updated with leveling, but that's the way the larger project wants to do it.

If it helps, we could also use Project 2013.

Answer (score 0):

The leveling delay is saved (as long as you save the file), even if the resources are removed.  As long as no one attempts to clear leveling, you should be all set.

Works the same in 2010 or 2013.